# Running Apache Spark on Windows 7

Tags: windows, apache-spark

I am trying to run *Apache Spark* on *Windows 7*. At first I have installed *SBT* by *msi*, then extracted files from `spark-1.0.0` to program files by *7-zip*. In the command line, I wrote the following:

```
spark-directory: sbt/sbt assembly
```

After a few seconds of processing, I got errors like:

```
-server access error: connection timed out
-could not retrieve jansi 1.1
-error during sbt execution: error retrieving required libraries
-unresolved dependency, jansi 1.1 not found
```

Could you please give me some advices about running *Spark* on *Windows*? I am looking for the right way because I am completely new with this technology. Regards.

Comment: I don't really get what I exactly need, Scala, jansi, hadoop?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the pre-built spark from [here](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html)

The scripts inside bin folder works in windows 7.
You need to set HADOOP_HOME variable in your path.

[spark on windows](http://docs.sigmoidanalytics.com/index.php/How_to_build_SPARK_on_Windows) for more information

Answer (score 0):

If you are using building with sbt approach, then you'll need git also.
Install Scala, sbt and git on your machine. Download [Spark source code](http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) and run following command

```
sbt assembly
```

In case,if you use prebuilt release,Here is the step by step process :
[How to run Apache Spark on Windows7 in standalone mode](http://nishutayaltech.blogspot.in/2015/04/how-to-run-apache-spark-on-windows7-in.html)